# Request-response, websocket or text event stream? What is best for Tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat, websocket, server-sent-events

In my web-application I need to show some real-time data to user. As I know there is few ways to realize it:

1. Websocket
2. EventStream
3. JS-timer, which sends a request to server each 1-2 seconds.

But which way is more lightweight for my Tomcat 8 server?

Comment: How many concurrent users do you expect?

Comment: Olaf Kock ~1000 users